# Lost bitcoin in a blocked transacion

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-transactions

I was trying to transfer some bitcoins from my bitcoin core wallet to another online wallet.
I did this transaction like 3 weeks ago. and I think I have lowered too much the fees.
The transaction was showing in my wallet as "unconfirmed" with 0 nodes.

Reading few messages on this forum I have used the -zapwallettxes option, and now the transaction is no longer showing in the transaction list. but at the same time my wallet is now empty.

Have I lost forever those bitcoins ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've deleted the transaction from your wallet, online explorers still probably have it. You can look up your recent wallet addresses in e.g. [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) and see if you can find the transaction and its status. (I'm assuming it's still unconfirmed, because otherwise your wallet should start showing it again.)

Comment: How can I look for my transaction if is not listed within bitcoin Core ? and assuming I can found it, how can I revert it if is not confirmed ?

Comment: Bitcoin Core should still have your addresses, if you look them up in an online explorer it should lead you to the transaction itself.

Comment: As planned, I can find the transaction on mempool, it is unconfirmed... and stuck there for weeks now. Can I increase the fee ? can I cancel the transaction ?  I need that amount ... please help...

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it